# All textView are modify in Custom ListAdapter after AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, adapter

I fill an **ArrayList <'HashMap <'String, String>>** with an AsyncTask and i set the adapter with my custom adapter , and i creat each view in `getView()` .
Until here , everything works.
Now i pet a listener on `linear_layout` to open an AlertDialog with EditTextField.
And when i want to change a textView after have to clicked , my textview change and when i scrool and i come back , the start value (that i get in Asynctask) appear. So it's like if the  value are not save at the position.

This is my getView() method :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    if (convertView == null) {
      holder = new CustomListingCrossHolder();  

      convertView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_type_tournee, null);       

      holder.miscellaneous = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.miscellaneous);
      holder.infos = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.infos);

      holder.linear_divers = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.test);

      convertView.setTag(holder);

     } else {
      holder = (CustomListingCrossHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }       

     holder.miscellaneous.setText(this.listItem.get(position).get("miscellaneous")); 
     holder.infos.setText(this.listItem.get(position).get("infos")); 

     holder.linear_divers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

          View alertDialogView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_divers, null);
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                  CustomListingCrossHolder cmh = (CustomListingCrossHolder) v.getTag();

                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);     

                final EditText input = new EditText(ctx);
                adb.setView(input);
                adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                    {                          
                      diver_edit = input.getText().toString();
                      holder.miscellaneous.setText(diver_edit); 
           // it's here where i change the textview

                    }
                });
                adb.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
                adb.create().show();

            }

        });      


     return convertView;
    }
```

and this is my holder class :

```
    private class CustomListingCrossHolder {

    TextView infos;
    TextView miscellaneous;
    LinearLayout linear_divers;

}
```

So i can't "save" the value of the `TextField` of the `AlertDialog` to the position and don't change when i scroll.May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

EDIT 1 : 
i call my listView in my OnPostExecute of my Asynctask 
this is the code where i set the adapter :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    this.pDialog.dismiss();

    Log.i("AsyncTaskListCrossingPoint", "onPostExecute");

    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject json_data = null;
    HashMap<String, String> map;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    if (!result.startsWith("error", 2)) {
        // recuperation des donnees json
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.i("tagjsonexp", "" + e.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.i("tagjsonpars", "" + e.toString());
        }
        Log.i("JARRAY", jArray.toString());

        // Insertion des données json dans un Hashmap
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            try {

                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("miscellaneous",json_data.getString("miscellaneous") != "null" ? json_data.getString("miscellaneous") : "Aucune");
                map.put("infos",json_data.getString("infos") != "null" ? json_data.getString("infos") : "Aucune");
                listItem.add(map);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        this.adapter = new CustomListingCrossAdapter(this.Mycontext, listItem);
        listview.setAdapter(this.adapter);

    }
}
```

and the code at the top of the post is the getView method which is in CustomListingCrossAdapter

Comment: How are you calling the function? and where are you calling it?

It would be interesting to see some of the code from where you make the call.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved my problem.
I put

```
final HashMap<String, String> object = (HashMap<String, String>) this.getItem(position);
```

to get the item at the position of the click and i put the new value with the same name key in my HashMap like this :

```
 holder.linear_divers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {                   

                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);     

                final EditText input = new EditText(ctx);
                adb.setView(input);
                adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                    {                          
                      diver_edit = input.getText().toString();                            
                      object.put("miscellaneous", diver_edit);
                      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                      Log.i("objet", "o : " + object.get("miscellaneous"));

                    }
                });
                adb.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
                adb.create().show();                    
            }               
        });
```